# How to group elements of a numpy array with the same value in separate numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, grouping

As usual intro, I am a tyro in python. However, I got quite a big project to code. It is a surface flow model with Cell Automata. Anyway, I also want to include building roofs in my model. Imagine you have an ascii file indicating buildings with 1s, while the rest is 0. There are just those two states. Now, I want to find all adjacent cells indicating the same building and store them (or rather the information of y,x and one more (maybe elevation),so 3 columns) in an individual building arrays. Keep in mind that buildings can have all possible forms though diagonally connected cells doesn't belong to the same building. So only northern, southern, western and eastern cells can belong to the same building.

I did my homework and googled it but so far I couldn't find a satisfying answer.

example:
initial land-cover array:

```
([0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
 [0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
 [0,1,1,1,0,1,1]
 [0,1,0,1,0,0,1]
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
```

output(I need to now the coordinates of the cells in my initial array):

```
 building_1=([1,2],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,3])
 building_2=([2,5],[2,6],[3,6])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think coordinates should be tuples, not lists (unless you plan to add extra dimensions to already constructed coordinates). Also you're probably looking for a list of coordinates, not a tuple. Instead of e.g. `building_2=([2,5],[2,6],[3,6])` you should be looking for `building_2=[(2,5),(2,6),(3,6)]`.

Comment: Oh scratch that it looks like numpy coordinates are returned as tuples of lists. Wat.

Comment: Sry, I was sloppy here. I wasn't referring to a specific output data type. But I would actually like to stick with numpy arrays since I use them over my whole algorithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html) function from `scipy.ndimage` to identify the distinct buildings.

Here's your example array, containing two buildings:

```
In [57]: a
Out[57]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Import `label`.

```
In [58]: from scipy.ndimage import label
```

Apply `label` to `a`.  It returns two values:  the array of labeled positions, and the number of distinct objects (buildings, in this case) found.

```
In [59]: lbl, nlbls = label(a)

In [60]: lbl
Out[60]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)

In [61]: nlbls
Out[61]: 2
```

To get the coordinates of a building, `np.where` can be used.  For example,

```
In [64]: np.where(lbl == 2)
Out[64]: (array([2, 2, 3]), array([5, 6, 6]))
```

It returns a tuple of arrays; the `k`th array holds the coordinates of the `k`th dimension.  You can use, for example, `np.column_stack` to combine these into an array:

```
 In [65]: np.column_stack(np.where(lbl == 2))
 Out[65]: 
 array([[2, 5],
        [2, 6],
        [3, 6]])
```

You might want a list of all the coordinate arrays.  Here's one way to create such a list.

For convenience, first create a list of labels:

```
In [66]: labels = range(1, nlbls+1)

In [67]: labels
Out[67]: [1, 2]
```

Use a list comprehension to create the list of coordinate arrays.

```
In [68]: coords = [np.column_stack(where(lbl == k)) for k in labels]

In [69]: coords
Out[69]: 
[array([[1, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 3]]),
 array([[2, 5],
       [2, 6],
       [3, 6]])]
```

Now your building data is in `labels` and `coords`.  For example, the first building was labeled `labels[0]`, and its coordinates are in `coords[0]`:

```
In [70]: labels[0]
Out[70]: 1

In [71]: coords[0]
Out[71]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 3]])
```

Comment: This can't be said better

Comment: very Pythonic! thanks! However, in my glorious foresight, I forgot to mention that my background information is not 0 but -9999 because it is a ascii file used in Geographic Information Systems. Otherwise your answer is great. I will post a suggestion. I wonder if you know an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the great answers! Here is a little correction. If you see the landcover array, I actually don't have 0 as background information but -9999 (0 is too precious for GIS people). I forgot to mention that. But thanks to machine yearning's hint, I made a work-around by assigning all -9999 with 0 through landcover = np.where(landcover > -9999, landcover, 0). After that I can use  label. The actual aim was to find the lowest cell and to assign it as outlet. If somebody has a more efficient way, please let me know!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import label
```

Original data set has -9999 as background information and 1 as building cells.

```
landcover = np.array([[-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,1], 
                       [-9999,-9999,1,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999],
                       [-9999,1,1,1,-9999,1,1], 
                       [-9999,1,-9999,1,-9999,-9999,1], 
                       [-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999]],dtype=int)
```

Here is a random digital elevation map.

```
DEM = np.array([[7,4,3,2,4,5,4], 
               [4,5,5,3,5,6,7],
               [2,6,4,7,4,4,4],
               [3,7,8,8,10,9,7],
               [2,5,7,7,9,10,8]],dtype=float)
```

I changed all -9999 entries to 0 in order to use label @thanks to machine yearning

```
 landcover = np.where(landcover > -9999, landcover, 0)
```

Then I labeled distinct buildings and counting those distinctions @Warren Weckesser, the rest pretty much yours. thanks!

```
 lbl, nlbls = label(landcover)
 bldg_number = range(1, nlbls+1)
 bldg_coord = [np.column_stack(where(lbl == k)) for k in bldg_no]
 outlets=np.zeros([nlbls,3])
```

I am iterating over the bldg_coord list in order to determine the lowest cells which will be assigned as outlet

```
 for i in range(0, nlbls):
     building=np.zeros([bldg_coord[i].shape[0],3])
     for j in range(0,bldg_coord[i].shape[0]):
         building[j][0]=bldg_coord[i][j][0]
         building[j][1]=bldg_coord[i][j][1]
         building[j][2]=DEM[bldg_coord[i][j][0],bldg_coord[i][j][1]]
```

I sort the building array in ascending order according to the DEM information of each building cell in order to find the lowest lying building cells.

```
  building=building[building[:,2].argsort()]
```

The lowest building cell will be used as roof outlet for rainwater

```
  outlets[i][0]=building[0][0]
  outlets[i][1]=building[0][1]
  outlets[i][2]=bldg_coord[i].shape[0]
```

Here is the output. The first two columns are indices in den landcover array and the last is the number of adjacent building cells.

```
>>> outlets
array([[ 0.,  6.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  6.],
       [ 2.,  5.,  3.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this function does exactly what you're looking for (from [the numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html#numpy.argwhere)):

> numpy.argwhere(a):
>
> Find the indices of array elements that are non-zero, grouped by element.

```
>>> x = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
>>> x
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> np.argwhere(x>1)
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```

Alternatively it seems like your use case requires using the returned coordinates to index arrays.

> The output of argwhere is not suitable for indexing arrays. For this purpose use where(a) instead.

You might want to try `numpy.where` instead.