# extract "block" addresses and value from 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm for extracting a rectangular address and value from a 2D numpy array in python.  The input looks something like this:

```
[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0],
 [0, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]]
```

Where there are various clusters of equal data at various locations in the array.  I'm trying to output it to a format that consists of the cluster start addresses (startY, startX), the cluster end addresses (endY, endX), and the value of that cluster, in a rectangular format.   So for the above 2D array above, the series of output values would look like this (I have excluded the zero values for the sake of brevity, but they would be included in the output):

```
(0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
(0, 6, 1, 6, 2)
(3, 3, 5, 5, 3)
(5, 1, 5, 2, 4)
(6, 6, 6, 6, 3)
```

Is there a function in numpy that can do something like this?  I have looked through the documentation, and I can't seem to find anything, though admittedly I'm quite new to numpy, so I might be missing something, or not putting together the logic of nesting functions to make the process 2-dimensional.

Thank you!

Comment: See if this can help you: [How to group elements of a numpy array with the same value in separate numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856169/how-to-group-elements-of-a-numpy-array-with-the-same-value-in-separate-numpy-arr)

Comment: Thank you!  I'll check this out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing the relevance of the 2nd array.

Just eye balling the first array, I can index the non-zero blocks with

```
In [738]: arr[0:2,0:2]
Out[738]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1]])

In [739]: arr[0:2,6:7]
Out[739]: 
array([[2],
       [2]])

In [740]: arr[3:6,3:6]
Out[740]: 
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3]])


In [741]: arr[5:6,1:3]
Out[741]: array([[4, 4]])

In [742]: arr[6:7,6:7]
Out[742]: array([[3]])
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I know how to get those values myself looking at the first array, and manually indexing it.  I'm looking for a built in function, or series of functions that will find and return those addresses automatically when passed the arrary.

Comment: The comment link suggests there might be something useful in image processing packages.  `numpy` itself is not going to have anything like this; it's too specialized to have a fast compiled implementation.  And too iterative to build from whole array operations.